# Remove some duplicates from list in python

Tags: python

UPDATE: I believe I found the solution. I've put it at the end.

Let’s say we have this list:

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c']
```

I want to create another list to remove the duplicates from list `a`, but at the same time, keep the ratio approximately intact AND maintain order.
The **output** should be:

```
b = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

EDIT: To explain better, the ratio doesn't need to be exactly intact. All that's required is the output of ONE single letter for all letters in the data. However, two letters might be the same but represent two different things. The counts are important to identify this as I say later. Letters representing ONE unique variable appear in counts between 3000-3400 so when I divide the total count by 3500 and round it, I know how many time it should appear in the end, but the problem is I don't know what order they should be in.

To illustrate this I'll include one more input and desired output:

- Input: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'd', 'd', 'a', 'a']
- Desired Output: ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a']

Note that 'C' has been repeated three times. The ratio needs not be preserved exactly, all I need to represent is how many times that variable is represented and because it's represented 3 times only in this example, it isn't considered enough for it to count as two.
The only difference is that here I'm assuming all letters repeating exactly twice are unique, although in the data-set, again, uniqueness is dependent on the appearance of 3000-3400 times.

Note(1): This doesn't necessarily need to be considered but there's a possibility that not all letters will be grouped together nicely, for example, considering 4 letters for uniqueness to make it short: ['a','a',''b','a','a','b','b','b','b'] should still be represented as ['a','b']. This is a minor problem in this case, however.

EDIT:
Example of what I've tried and successfully done:

```py
full_list = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c'] 
#full_list is a list containing around 10k items, just using this as example
rep = 2 # number of estimated repetitions for unique item, 
# in the real list this was set to 3500

quant = {'a': 0, "b" : 0, "c" : 0, "d" : 0, "e" : 0, "f" : 0, "g": 0}
for x in set(full_list):
    quant[x] = round(full_list.count(x)/rep)


final = []

for x in range(len(full_list)):
    if full_list[x] in final:
        lastindex = len(full_list) - 1 - full_list[::-1].index(full_list[x])

        if lastindex == x and final.count(full_list[x]) < quant[full_list[x]]:
            final.append(full_list[x])
    else:
        final.append(full_list[x])
print(final)
```

My problem with the above code is two-fold:

- If there are more than 2 repetitions of the same data, it will not count them correctly. For example:  ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a'] should become ['a','b','a','c','a'] but instead it becomes ['a','b,'c','a']
- It takes a very log time to finish as I'm sure it's a very
  inefficient way to do this.

Final remark: The code I've tried was more of a little hack to achieve the desired output on the most common input, however it doesn't do exactly what I intended it to. It's also important to note that the input changes over time. Repetitions of single letters aren't always the same, although I believe they're always grouped together, so I was thinking of making a flag that is True when it hits a letter and becomes false as soon as it changes to a different one, but this also has the problem of not being able to account for the fact that two letters that are the same might be put right next to each other. The count for each letter as an individual is always between 3000-3400, so I know that if the count is above that, there are more than 1.

UPDATE: Solution
Following hiro protagonist's suggestion with minor modifications, the following code seems to work:

```py
full = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a']
from itertools import groupby
letters_pre = [key for key, _group in groupby(full)]
letters_post = []
for x in range(len(letters_pre)):
    if x>0 and letters_pre[x] != letters_pre[x-1]:
        letters_post.append(letters_pre[x])
    if x == 0:
        letters_post.append(letters_pre [x])
print(letters_post)
```

The only problem is that it doesn't consider that sometimes letters can appear in between unique ones, as described in "Note(1)", but that's only a very minor issue. The bigger issue is that it doesn't consider when two separate occurances of the same letter are consecutive, for example (two for uniqueness as example): ['a','a','a','a','b','b'] gets turned to ['a','b'] when desired output should be ['a','a','b']

Comment: kindly add some piece of code that you have tried.

Comment: can you atleast add some more examples, specifically showcasing your statement about ratios? say, how should a list such as `lst = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b']` be resolved?

Comment: If ratio needs to be exact than you need counts of all the unique elements. You then need the greatest common divisor (gcd) of these counts and then you would need to remove upon encountering over the (count/gcd)th repeated element. If ratio does not need to be exact you need to make clear the rule for deleting.

Comment: I've edited to include code I've tried.

Comment: to answer your comment about downvotes read up in the help center (top right  > question mark) about the site. Downvotes are a signal of how useful the question will be to the wider community and also of the question quality. Your question won't ever help anyone else and was also badly asked. Initially no code and is now way too long. Question and code should be a [mcve]

Comment: I will read it. I appreciate your answer, thank you. Makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is where [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) may come in handy:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = ["a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "c", "c"]

res = [key for key, _group in groupby(a)]
print(res)  # ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

---

this is a version where you could 'scale' down the unique keys (but are guaranteed to have at leas one in the result):

```
from itertools import groupby, repeat, chain

a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a',  
     'd', 'd', 'a', 'a']
scale = 0.4

key_count = tuple((key, sum(1 for _item in group)) for key, group in groupby(a))
# (('a', 4), ('b', 2), ('c', 5), ('a', 2), ('d', 2), ('a', 2))

res = tuple(
    chain.from_iterable(
        (repeat(key, round(scale * count) or 1)) for key, count in key_count
    )
)
# ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'd', 'a')
```

there may be smarter ways to determine the `scale` (probably based on the length of the input list `a` and the average `group` length).

Comment: It only works if list `a` consists in letters repeated exactly the same number of times each time. Otherwise, this doesn't preserve the ratio

Comment: OP may not understand the usage of `groupby`, moreover he hasn't produced a code he has tried. This encourages users to post just a question without any attempt.

Comment: does not work for `a = ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"]`

Comment: This actually works for my specific problem but there's one little issue. How do I keep only one single copy of each grouped items, like: ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'c, 'c', 'c'] into only ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c'] ?
I've also edited my question to be more precise.

Comment: oh, the question has changed a lot since my answer!

Comment: It has, but the irony is I believe I have just found the solution based on your suggestion :p

Comment: @Reacf if this answer has helped you please accept it

Comment: I did. Thank you.

Comment: Quick question, I’m new here so I’m a bit confused. Should I have posted this somewhere else, or phrased it differently? I’m not sure why there are so many downvotes.

Comment: oh, thanks! i did not follow when the downvotes happened; but i guess it was when you first posted your question without any attempt to a solution. that is frowned upon here... now the question seems totally fine to me. will upvote.

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try it out and I’ll also try to make it as efficient as possible. This already helped make it almost instant from the initial 45 seconds using my previous not-even-accurate code.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a strange one, but:

```
b = []
for i in a:
    if next(iter(b[::-1]), None) != i:
        b.append(i)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: this is a very weird way of approaching the problem! i like it a lot!

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Haha, your solution is the best way, i know it, but i forgot to use it :P i am kinda hacking :P, simply iterate then append if it isn't the last element :P took some time to think of that logic.

Comment: Oh that’s a very smart way to approach it. I’ll try it out :)